# Developing Amazon Alexa skill and I am having trouble with slot values (acronyms) being read as words

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am building a TV guide as an Amazon Alexa skill and have all of the necessary parts working (I.E. Lambda, DynamoDB, and Alexa Skill console) where the majority of channels will be recognized by voice, found in my database, and returned.

The reason for this question is I want Alexa to take my voice input of "BET", but every time I spell out BET, she doesn't recognize the slot. If I say "bet" she will recognize the slot, uppercase the slot (part of my lambda function), match to word in my database, and return the item. I would prefer to spell out the word rather than just say "bet".

How do I ensure that when I spell out "BET" that Alexa will understand "BET" and not "bet"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are properly tokenizing the abbreviations in your slots  in addition to your utterances, this will allow Alexa to match what you are saying to the values:

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-voice-interface-and-user-experience-testing#writing-conventions-for-sample-utterances

"BET" would become "B. E. T."

You may have to adjust your Lambda code to expect these new values (perhaps all it would take is a REGEX replace on the slot value).

--

Edit: For channels like FOX, it might make sense to include both "FOX" and "F. O. X." (as well as any common spoken alternatives) as slot values and process them on the Lambda side.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The advice on the RegEx has been super helpful so far.

Comment: CNN also?  Also can you choose the accepted answer?

Comment: This answer is wrong. In a sentence, "I am a person who watches B. E. T." would be spoken by Alexa with an awkward end-of-sentence pause after "B.". There should not be any spaces. "B. E. T." should be "B.E.T."

Comment: @fivedogit you're right about output--but the original question seems to be around input.